# Twitter status update api not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am trying to tweet using this sample program and getting an error 
I am following this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter)

Here is the code

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: 'CONSUMER_KEY',
    consumer_secret: 'CONSUMER_SECRET',
    access_token: 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    access_token_secret: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'
});

//var stat = ["First Tweet","Second Tweet","Third Tweet","Forth Tweet","Fifth Tweet"];

client.post('statuses/update', {status: 'I Love Twitter'},  function(error, tweet, response){
  if(error) throw error;
  console.log(tweet);  // Tweet body. 
  console.log(response);  // Raw response object. 
});
```

whenever i run this code i receive following error

```
E:\Local server\nodejs\status_update\test.js:12
  if(error) throw error;
                  ^
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way. Fixed mine.

```
client.post('statuses/update', {status: "words"}, function(error, tweet, response){
  if (!error) {
    console.log(tweet);
  }
});
```